# Unexpected lower access time in multiple process scenario as compared to single process scenario

Tags: c, performance, gcc, performance-testing, cpu-architecture

I am accessing a shared library (shared array data structure)from program1 and find the access time to read all elements of that array. I got around 17000 ticks while only Program1 executed alone.

Now when I execute program2 (having empty while loop to hold it from termination) in another tab first , then run program1 and measure the access time to read all elements of that array.
To my surprise now I am getting 8000ticks as compared to previous scenario where only Program1 executing.

It looks like while ONLY program1 is executing it takes more time to read the array as compared to while there are 2 Programs ,program1 is doing same task as previous and program2 keeps CPU busy by while loop. Expected is higher access time with presence of program1, whereas real outcome is opposite .

Why this happening?

Here is shared library

```
#include <stdio.h> 
static const int DATA[1024]={1 ,2 ,3,.....1024];
inline void foo(void)
{
    int j, k=0,count=0;

    for(j=0;j<1024;j++)
      {
        k=DATA[j];
      }

    k+=0;    
}
```

**Program1**

```
   int main(void)
    {    
    foo();

    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("Time1=%llu\n",end-start);    

    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("Time2=%llu\n",end-start);    


    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("Time3=%llu\n",end-start); 
    sleep(1);

    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("after sleep(1)\n");
    printf("Time4=%llu\n",end-start);    

    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("Time5=%llu\n",end-start);    

    sleep(2); 
    start=timer();
    foo();
    end=timer();
    printf("after sleep(2)\n");
    printf("Time6=%llu\n",end-start);    

    return 0;
    }
```

**program2**

```
   int main(void)
    {
    while(1)
        {}        
    return 0;
    }
```

**CASE1 (ONLY Program1 running)**

**output**

```
Time1=17918
Time2=17672  
Time3=17816  

after sleep(1)
**Time4= 20716 ** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
Time5=17722

after sleep(2)
**Time6=20910** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
```

**CASE1 (Program2 runs first, then Program1 starts running)**

**output**

```
Time1 =7483  
Time2=7205
Time3=7399

after sleep(1)
**Time4= 8734 ** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
Time5=7326

after sleep(2)
**Time6=9070** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
```

As per my understanding while CPU is used by program1 alone time required to read array must be less as compared to while CPU is used by both Program1 and program2.

Where I am making mistakes ? I have i7 machine , only one core , hyperthreading is disabled, ASLR disabled.

**EDIT 1:**

As per suggestion of Mysticial, my CPU goes into power saving mode while ONLY program1 is there , so CPU goes into power saving mode and then to wake it up from Power saving mode it takes larger access time. So his suggestion was to access the DATA array multiple times.

Here is my modified Shared library . Program1 and Program2 are unaltered.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
static const int DATA[1024]={1 ,2 ,3,.....1024];
inline void foo(void)
{
    int j, k=0,count=0;
  while(count++<10000)
  {  
    for(j=0;j<1024;j++)
      {
        k=DATA[j];
      }
   }  
    k+=0;    
}
```

**Now the output is as below**

**CASE1 (ONLY Program1 running)**

**output**

```
Time1=75186246
Time2=77570299 
Time3=80548529 

after sleep(1)
**Time4= 92608363 ** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
Time5=75616487

after sleep(2)
**Time6=97021338** // Is it due to wake up from sleep mode ?
```

**CASE1 (Program2 runs first, then Program1 starts running)**

**output**

```
Time1 =139337099 
Time2=155801957
Time3=146586856

after sleep(1)
**Time4= 130558062 ** // Why lower access time after sleep mode ?
Time5=145250551 // Time5 is expected lower than Time4 as other run . Why lower here ?

after sleep(2)
**Time6=130940183** // Again Why lower access time after sleep mode ?
```

**Here are my new questions with respect to modified shared library**

1. When there is no program2, then after sleep access time (t4/t6) is **higher**  as compared to previous access time (t3/t5, before going to sleep). Can I say, it is due to waking up CPU from sleep as explained by Mysticial ?
2. Now, with program2 running in another tab, after sleep access time (t4/t6) is **lower**  as compared to previous access time (t3/t5, before going to sleep). Reason for my q(1) and q(2) are contradictory . What is the reason behind getting lower access time after waking up from sleep ( t4 < t3)? Although I am getting higher access time after sleep without multiple access to DATA array ( original shared library).
3. Why `t2<t1 and t3<t2` not holding true always as shared library is loaded already into memory as well as cache . Is it due to PAGE SWAPPING ?

I am using gcc under linux. Any help to understand this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The benchmark is almost meaningless unless you run multiple iterations. (Enough iterations so that the benchmark lasts several seconds rather than instantaneous.) As it is with a single iteration, you're probably seeing the effects of program2 forcing the CPU to go out of power-saving state.

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks for answering. You mean to say, when I use single iteration to read the same array CPU goes into power saving state and that's why I am getting higher access time (17000ticks). When Program2 use while loop and keeps CPU busy then it prevents CPU to goes into power saving state. May be you are right, as when I use sleep(100) in program2 then also I got higher (17000 ticks) access time. Let me check with multiple iterations and then I will post the results here.

Comment: @Mysticial I am getting the expected result ( higher access time while program2 is in scenario) with multiple iteration(10000). Can you write this as an answer so that I can accept this. Thank you .

Comment: Since you already have a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676633/difference-between-use-of-while-and-sleep-to-put-program-into-sleep-mode) (with some answers), it would be appropriate to link there in case there's some helpful information.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my speculative answer which seems to have been confirmed in the comments:

In the original benchmark, you run only one iteration of each. So the benchmark doesn't run long enough to "average out" all the randomness.

When you run program1 by itself, it needs to wake up the CPU from its power-saving state. This takes time and is likely causing the run-time to be longer.

When you run both programs together (starting with program2 first), program2 kicks the CPU out of power-saving state ahead of time. So this warm up penalty is not realized when you run program1.

---

Once you loop the benchmark to take longer, this warm up penalty becomes insignificant and you finally see the expected steady-state performance of the code. (program1 by itself is faster)

Comment: +1 for the loop iterations, but I'm not sure about the power states. Unless the programs are affinitized to the same core they're likely to run on different ones, which can go in and out of power states separately (there wouldn't be much sense in these powerstates unless you had this granularity because the other core won't enjoy the dynamic turbo).

Comment: @Leeor In my machine I have disabled other core as well as Hyper threading.

Comment: @bholanath TBH, in the program2 + program1 case for your new benchmarks, there's so much noise that I can't really draw the same conclusions. As far as I can tell, they're all the same within the variation.

Comment: @Mysticial what is TBH ? Another point, if you see the access times then there is lower/higher access time mix. there is no pattern followed. Like first access time is higher as it is accessed from main memory, consecutive access time will be lower as they are accessed from cache. What I am getting here ( with/with multiple access to same array) sometimes I am getting lower access time than previous( as expected), but sometimes higher access time later ( lower access time expected, WHY higher access time?)

Comment: I'm saying that your there's too much noise (at least for me) to draw any conclusions. You have `Time1 =139337099` and `Time2=155801957`. Which already shows a huge variation. Sure with the sleep it might be a bit lower that that. Personally, I don't consider it statistically significant. You may have more data points, but as far as I can see I can't jump to any conclusions.

Comment: But even if is consistently lower in the long run, I have no explanation for that. The only other thing I can turn to is the OS task scheduler which is another black box - that I'm less familiar with. I'm not sure whether it's worth trying to track this all the way to the last bit. I'm better versed at investigating steady-state performance anomalies, not the warm-up periods.